# how do i Inherit return values from parent class and plot them in the child class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

so i have a parent class that is working fine but i'm struggling to get the return values from the parent class and plot them with child class. ideally, i would call a method from the parent class (the child class calls the method) and use the return values in the child class and plot them. the child class should be able to take the same arguments as the parent class.

parent class:

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import FTestAnovaPower
class PwrAnalysis:
    def __init__(self, effect_size=None, nobs=None, alpha=None, alpha2=None, power=None, k_groups=None, rng1=None, rng2=None):
        self.effect_size = effect_size
        self.nobs = nobs
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.alpha2 = alpha2
        self.power = power
        self.k_groups = k_groups
        self.rng1 = rng1
        self.rng2 = rng2

    def pwr_vs_smpl_sz(self):
       
        pwr_vs_smpl_1 = []
        pwr_vs_smpl_2 = []

        for pwr_rng in self.rng1:
            pwr_vs_smpl_1.append(FTestAnovaPower().solve_power(effect_size=self.effect_size,
                                        nobs=None, alpha=self.alpha, power=pwr_rng, k_groups=self.k_groups))
        
        for pwr_rng in self.rng2:
            pwr_vs_smpl_2.append(FTestAnovaPower().solve_power(effect_size=self.effect_size,
                                        nobs=None, alpha=self.alpha2, power=pwr_rng, k_groups=self.k_groups))
        
        return  [pwr_vs_smpl_1, self.rng1], [pwr_vs_smpl_2, self.rng2]

    def pwr_vs_effct_sz(self):
        pwr_vs_effect_size_1 = []
        pwr_vs_effect_size_2 = []
        

        for pwr_rng in self.rng1:
            pwr_vs_effect_size_2.append(FTestAnovaPower().solve_power(effect_size=None,
                                        nobs=self.nobs, alpha=self.alpha, power=pwr_rng, k_groups=self.k_groups))
        for pwr_rng in self.rng2:
            pwr_vs_effect_size_2.append(FTestAnovaPower().solve_power(effect_size=None,
                                        nobs=self.nobs, alpha=self.alpha2, power=pwr_rng, k_groups=self.k_groups))
        
        return  [pwr_vs_effect_size_1, self.rng1], [pwr_vs_effect_size_2, self.rng2]
            
    def smpl_sz_vs_effct_sz(self):
        sample_size_vs_effect_size_1 = []
        sample_size_vs_effect_size_2 = []
        
       
        for num_of_smpls in self.rng1:
            sample_size_vs_effect_size_1.append(FTestAnovaPower().solve_power(effect_size=None,
                                        nobs=num_of_smpls, alpha=self.alpha, power=self.power, k_groups=self.k_groups))
        for num_of_smpls in self.rng2:
            sample_size_vs_effect_size_2.append(FTestAnovaPower().solve_power(effect_size=None,
                                        nobs=num_of_smpls, alpha=self.alpha2, power=self.power, k_groups=self.k_groups))        
            
        return  [sample_size_vs_effect_size_1, self.rng1], [sample_size_vs_effect_size_2, self.rng2]
```

child class:

```
class PwrPlots(PwrAnalysis):
    def __init__(self, effect_size=None, nobs=None, alpha=None, alpha2=None, power=None, k_groups=None, rng1=None, rng2=None):
        super().__init__(effect_size=None, nobs=None, alpha=None, alpha2=None, power=None, k_groups=None, rng1=None, rng2=None)

    def plt_pwr_vs_smpl(self):

        # plot 1
        plt.plot(super().pwr_vs_smpl_1, self.rng1, 'b', marker='o', label=f'alpha={self.alpha:.2f}')
        
        #plot 2

        plt.plot(super().pwr_vs_smpl_2, self.rng2, 'b', marker='o', label=f'alpha={self.alpha:.2f}')
        
        
#         # labels, title, legend etc...
#         plt.title('Power vs Sample size')
#         plt.xlabel('Power')
#         plt.ylabel('Sample Size')
#         plt.legend(loc="lower right")
#         #plt.grid()
       
    
#     def plt_pwr_vs_effct_sz(self):


   

#     def plt_smpl_sz_vs_effct_sz(self):
```

Comment: You don't need to use `super()`. Since methods are inherited, you can just call `self.pwr_vs_smpl_1(...)`

Comment: `pwr_vs_smpl_1` is not a method in the parent class. It's a local variable inside the `pwr_vs_smpl_sz()` method, and not accessible anywhere else.

Comment: No inheritance is needed. `PwrPlots.plt_pwr_vs_smpl` could simply be a function that takes an instance of `PwrAnalysis` as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You should call that parent function and just take the value it returned:

```
class PwrPlots(PwrAnalysis):
    def plt_pwr_vs_smpl(self):
        # you can use self if you don't override that function in base class
        result = self.pwr_vs_smpl_sz() 
        # result contains list of two elements
        pwr_vs_smpl_1, pwr_vs_smpl_2 = result[0][0], result[1][0]
        # plot 1
        plt.plot(pwr_vs_smpl_1, self.rng1, 'b', marker='o', label=f'alpha={self.alpha:.2f}')
        ...
```